# Iframe HTML, help to make the URL change dynamically depending on hover

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a problem making my iframe changing dynamically depending on what I hover.
I have the following code made in vue:

```
<template>
<div>
     <div class="row">
       <h2> Ad performance </h2>
        </div>
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Client</th>
                        <th scope="col">Ad</th>
                        <th scope="col">Impressions</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="(ad, name) in adPerformance.slice(0,15)" :key="ad.adID">
                    <td>{{ad.client}}</td>
                    <td @mouseover="mouseEnter">{{ad.ad}}</td>
                    <td>{{ad.impressions}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h4> Desktop preview </h4>
                <iframe src= "!!!Change this dynamically!!!"
                v-show="toShowOnHover" @mouseleave="mouseLeave"
                width="800" height="700">
                </iframe>
              </div>
         </div>
</div>
</template>
<script>
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
 data() {
  return {
  toShowOnHover: false,
  };
 },
 props: ['adPerformance'],
 components: {
 },
 methods: {
  mouseEnter: function(){
   this.toShowOnHover = !this.toShowOnHover;
  },
  mouseLeave: function(){
   this.toShowOnHover = false;
  }
 },
  created() {
  },
};
</script>
```

On my local host server, I have tons of ad preview urls, that I want to dynamically change the src in the iframe depending on what Ad you hover.
The type of data on my local host look like this: [image]

Can anyone help making a code to getting these previewURL's into the iframe?
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, bind the src attribute of the iframe to a variable. Then change the mouseover handler so that it can get the previewURL and set the variable you have chosen to this url.

On mouse leaves set the variable to null.

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="row">
      <h2>Ad performance</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <table class="table table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">Client</th>
              <th scope="col">Ad</th>
              <th scope="col">Impressions</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr v-for="(ad) in adPerformance.slice(0,15)" :key="ad.adID">
              <td>{{ad.client}}</td>
              <td @mouseover="mouseEnter(ad.previewURL)">{{ad.ad}}</td>
              <td>{{ad.impressions}}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h4>Desktop preview</h4>
        <iframe
          :src="iframeURL"
          v-show="toShowOnHover"
          @mouseleave="mouseLeave"
          width="800"
          height="700"
        ></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      toShowOnHover: false,
      iframeURL: null
    };
  },
  props: ["adPerformance"],
  components: {},
  methods: {
    mouseEnter: function(url) {
      this.toShowOnHover = true;
      this.iframeURL = url;
    },
    mouseLeave: function() {
      this.toShowOnHover = false;
      this.iframeURL = null;
    }
  },
  created() {}
};
</script>
```

Comment: This is why we, developers, gain the fame of "copy and pasting from Stackoverflow" xD anyhow I think you have a tiny misspelling in `:src="iframeSrc"` I think what you meant was `:src="iframeURL"`.

Comment: @JoseFernández Thanks. Actually I tested the code in an online editor and at the end forgot to change all `iframeSrc` to `iframeURL`.

Answer (score 1):

I think asking from people to make you your piece of code is not a good way of learning from problems, so I will just explain you what you could do and if you have any question just shoot!!

You can send into the @mouseover the previewURL as `@mouseover="() => mouseEnter(ad.previewURL)"`

You can create a local variable as `previewURL`, and in the `mouseEnter` function you can assign `previewUrl` with the parameter you are receiving.

So `<iframe :src="previewURL" .../>`

This `previewURL` variable is reactive so if you change it the iframe src will change as well.